# jQuery .val() not changing input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked at the other related posts on stack overflow but still cant get this working.

Should be very simple.

I have this jQuery and HTML code:

```js
$('.add-headset').click(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'ADD') {
    $(this).text('REMOVE');
    $('.buy-headset').val('hiii');
  } else {
    $(this).text('ADD');
    $('.buy-headset').val(0);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="add-headset">ADD</div>
<input type="text" name="buy_headset" class="buy-headset" value="0" hidden />
```

The text changes between ADD and Remove fine, but the value of the input field is not changing. I don't understand as I do pretty much the same thing with a different element underneath and this works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't use `val()` to set the value of a `div` element. Use `.append()` instead.

Comment: s0 y0u want to change text for $('.buy-headset') ?

Comment: I want to change the value of the input field with the class of buy-headset

Comment: Seems to working fine... https://jsfiddle.net/j23hprbc/ (note, removed the invalid `hidden` attribute)

Comment: The value _is_ changing. The question is - why do you have a `text` input that you're not displaying? Isn't that what `hidden` inputs are for?

Comment: Just do `console.log($('.buy-headset').val())` inside click at last. It is getting correct value everytime.

Comment: Note that `val()` updates the value property of the element, not the attribute, so the change will not be visible in the DOM, even though the call worked.

Comment: @DragoşPaulMarinescu 1 it's an `input type=text` not a div 2 if you use `.append()` it won't *change* the value, it will just keep adding new values.  At least suggest using `.text()` or `.html()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the input *is* changing:

[image: Properties from Chrome debugger]

What's probably confusing you is that the `value` *attribute* doesn't change, and this is the way it's supposed to be. The attribute contains the control's initial value, not necessarily its current value.

Comment: Thanks! been scratching my head all day aha